# how to insert and view the data to sqlite database programmatically in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite

i can able to create table to my sqlite data base but i can't able to view that tables in terminal this my code

```
-(void)initDatabase
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sql"];

    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
        {
            // Create the PERSON table
            const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, BIRTHDAY DATE)";
            char *error;
            if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                // Create the ADDRESS table with foreign key to the PERSON table
                sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADDRESS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, STREETNAME TEXT, STREETNUMBER INT, PERSONID INT, FOREIGN KEY(PERSONID) REFERENCES PERSON(ID))";
                if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Database and tables created.");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my console output `Database and tables created.`

then i try to open that database in terminal like this

```
p-mac001:~ Th$ sqlite3 /Users/Th/Desktop/sample/Database.sql 
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
```

i can't able to see any tables kindly guide me where i'm doing wrong..

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426938/how-can-i-save-data-to-sqlite-database-in-iphone/9427095#9427095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested this with iPhone 5.0 Simulator, and your code works.

```
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-25 16:35:41
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
ADDRESS  PERSON
```

EDIT:

Here you have my code, it's exactly like yours:

```
#import <sqlite3.h>

@implementation FFViewController
-(void)initDatabase
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.sql"];

    bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    sqlite3 *databaseHandle = NULL;

    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
        {
            // Create the PERSON table
            const char *sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, BIRTHDAY DATE)";
            char *error;
            if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                // Create the ADDRESS table with foreign key to the PERSON table
                sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADDRESS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, STREETNAME TEXT, STREETNUMBER INT, PERSONID INT, FOREIGN KEY(PERSONID) REFERENCES PERSON(ID))";
                if (sqlite3_exec(databaseHandle, sqlStatement, NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Database and tables created.");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initDatabase];
}

@end
```

Comment: where did u add your Database.sql file? inside of app or ?

Comment: I didn't, I used your code that creates it. So in my case is something like /Users/fbernardo/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/.../Documents/Database.sql

Comment: can you post your code here for creating Database.sql file. i mean how to create that file and how to add that file to project? ..

Comment: how did u enter into this database using terminal i mean this line p-mac001:~ Th$ sqlite3 /Users/Th/Desktop/sample/Database.sql

Comment: You are creating a file named Database.sql in your Application's Documents folder, not on some other path. Insert the line NSLog(@"%@", databasePath); before your sqlite3_open to log the database file path. Then do sqlite3 <path printed out on log>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8342/discussion-between-moorthy-and-fbernardo)